# Easiest way to iterate through python list in batches

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
entries = [{"name": "some_name", "age": "some_age"...}, {"name": "some_other_name", "age": "some_other_age"}, ...]
```

and I want to iterate through in batches in 10 but this doesn't work:

```
 x = zip(*[iter(entries)]*10)
>>> x
<zip object at 0x1103db730>
>>> list(x)
[]
```

What I want is to eventually get an array of arrays of length 10 but I get nothing. The last array may have fewer than 10 elements. What can I do?

Comment: You probably want to use `itertools.zip_longest` so that it produces a partial list instead of discarding it.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
chunks = [data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0,len(data),chunk_size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should do what you're looking for. I don't know if there's a built-in function to do that.

This shares a lot of the same ideas as @Scott Hunter's answer, but laid out a little differently.

```py
def batches(seq):
    for x in range(0, len(seq), 10):
        yield seq[x:x + 10]
```